# Why less than operator is not giving the right answer?

Tags: javascript

I have two input fields and want to compare them using less than operator. If i insert value less than 10 in one field and greater than 10 in other field and use less operator between them its not showing the right answer

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("h1").value;
  alert(x);
  if(y > x)
 alert("good");
  else
 alert("ok");
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="myInput" onchange="myFunction()"/>
<input type="number" id="h1"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

The `typeof` of both the `input type='number'` is string. So before doing comparison change to number. You can do that either using `parseInt` or by using unary operator

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("h1").value;
  console.log(typeof(x), typeof(y))
  if (parseInt(y, 10) > parseInt(x, 10))
    alert("good");
  else
    alert("ok");
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="myInput" onchange="myFunction()" />
<input type="number" id="h1" />
```